# Seemingly Asynchronous Page Load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am not sure what to call this but in google plus, when you navigate to different pages, the HTTP address changes but the userbars seem to remain static and not reload.  What is happening and how is this done?

I hope this makes sense!  Thank you!

Comment: using ajax() .. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ... ajax you can load certain content in a page with out refreshing the page :)

Comment: But the http header remains static, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### AJAX (Asynchronously loading the content)

The content is being loading asynchronously and the url in the address bar is being altered.

An basic example of loading content asynchronously:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.net/load.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        // This will replace all content in the body tag with what has been retrieved
        $('body').html(data);
    }
});
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `$.ajax()` documentation.

### Modifying the URL without Redirecting

To change the url withour redirecting, you need to use the HTML5 history API. A similar question has been asked here before, please see:

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Extracted answer:

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);
}
```

For more information on the HTML5 History API, please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: I understand.  I was hoping for something...more elegant?  Thank you for the code example!

Comment: @user1909186 By more elegant, do you mean by using a library?

Comment: Not sure exactly.  I thought it might be something new that I wouldn't have thought of.  XHR/AJAX were the ways that I was thinking.  I guess I could make a library, but pjax looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that they're using the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history), specifically the `pushState` method to add new history states. They're also probably using Ajax ([XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)) to load in new content and then adding that content to the page via the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM).

Check out [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax), a library that takes care of most of this for you.

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look.  Thank you!  If you have any convenient code examples, that would be great, too!

Comment: @user1909186 You should check out pjax -- just added a link in the answer :)

Comment: Thank you!  It's late.  I realized that I know what you are talking about after all!